# Python AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'exit'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.9.12 and I get error in the following line

```
os.exit()
```

the Error message is: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'exit'

Comment: Im sure it shouldnt have worked with v3.9 either. `exit()` is builtin now.

Answer (score 3):

`os.exit()` is not and was not a method of the `os` module.
You may confuse it with `os._exit()` or `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 1):

As from comment, `exit` is a built-in. So `os.exit()` becomes `exit()`

Comment: `os.exit()` was never a method of os

Answer (score 1):

make sure variable **os** not been overwrited, like filename or varable name ...